# How to export header and library build flags for non-catkin projects?

Tags: ros, catkin, external-libraries, include

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some of our in-house ROS nodes, I want to link against some of our proprietary headers and libraries, none of which are built using catkin or cmake. What I would like to do is create a ROS package that acts as a wrapper, so that all my other ROS packages can just list the wrapper package as a dependency, and all the include and library C++ flags that point to our proprietary software are automatically included. What's the most efficient way to do that?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/150441/how-to-export-header-and-library-build-flags-for-non-catkin-projects?/) by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13689 on 2014-04-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The easiest way to provide custom CMake logic with a catkin package is using an extras file:

http://docs.ros.org/api/catkin/html/dev_guide/generated_cmake_api.html#catkin_package

This allows you to specify a cmake file for catkin to `include(...)` anytime that package is `find_package`'ed.

Related:

http://answers.ros.org/question/93266/how-to-export-non-standard-include-directories-in-catkin/

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tom Moore](https://answers.ros.org/users/3384/tom-moore/) on 2014-04-08**:
Great, thank you.